# excute CMD commands in php on local server Xampp

Tags: php, cmd, command-line-interface, shell-exec, whois

I want to run CMD commands in php through shell_exec() function to get the domain details. When I try `$detail = "whois " . "google.com";
        echo $res = shell_exec($detail);`

on online php editor it return correct information but when I run this code on local server Xampp it shows blank screen does not show any result or any error.

Comment: you are not echoing the result of the shell_exec()?

Comment: Do not shell out to run the whois command from PHP, as there is no need to and a lot of drawbacks. You have multiple libraries in any language, including PHP, to do whois queries. At the very least, whois is a simple query/response protocol over TCP/43 so that can be done from inside PHP very easily.